# Angular observable handling multiple subscribers

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

In my component's ngOnInit, ComProductService will first get the product categories and process the third level of category and store into proCatThird in the service. Then in my fillFormValues() method, i need to get proCatThird value from ComProductService. However, the value returned from proCatThird is undefined. Are there any proper ways to pass value from one subscriber to another?

ComProductService.service.ts

```
export class ComProductService {
 baseUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'comProducts/';
 proCatThird: ProCatThird[];
constructor(private http: HttpClient,
 private authService: AuthService,
 private errorHandler: ErrorService) { }

 getProductCategories(): Observable<ProCatFirst[]> {
  return this.http
   .get(this.baseUrl)
   .pipe(
    map((response: ProCatFirst[]) => {
     if (response) {
      this.proCatThird = [];
      response.forEach((first) => {
        first.proCatSeconds.forEach((second) => {
          second.proCatThirds.forEach((third) => {
            this.proCatThird.push(third);
          });
        });
      });
      return response;
    }
  })
);
}
```

component.ts

```
constructor(
private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
private comProductService: ComProductService,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.comProductService.getProductCategories().subscribe((response) => {
  this.proCatFirst = response;
});

this.fillFormValues();

}

fillFormValues() {

  this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
    this.product = data['product'];
    this.productForm.patchValue({
        name: this.product.name,
        category: this.product.category,
    });

    const catName = this.comProductService.proCatThird.find(pct => pct.id === this.product.category).name;
  });
}
```

Comment: The call `this.comProductService.getProductCategories()` is async in the `ngOnInit()` function. So the next line i.e. `this.fillFormValues()` is called before your http call completes. This could be causing `this.comProductService.proCatThird` to be undefined. Try calling the `fillFormValues()` method just after handing the response at `this.proCatFirst = response;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code right now is that the fillForm is initiated without waiting for the server response and the `proCatThird` property is not filled with the desired response.

Please do this in your component:

```
constructor(
private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
private comProductService: ComProductService,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.comProductService.getProductCategories().subscribe((response) => {
    this.proCatFirst = response;
    this.fillFormValues(); // fill form values when the data has been received from server
  });
}

fillFormValues() {
  this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
    this.product = data['product'];
    this.productForm.patchValue({
        name: this.product.name,
        category: this.product.category,
    });

    const catName = this.comProductService.proCatThird.find(pct => pct.id === this.product.category).name;
  });
}
```

### EDIT: SUGGESTION for Subscribe within Subscribe

```
    ngOnInit() {
      this.comProductService.getProductCategories()
        .pipe(
          mergeMap((response) => {
            this.proCatFirst = response;
been received from server
            return this.activatedRoute.data;
          })
        )
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.product = data['product'];
          this.productForm.patchValue({
              name: this.product.name,
              category: this.product.category,
          });

          const catName = this.comProductService.proCatThird.find(pct => pct.id === this.product.category).name;
        });

    }
```

This way, you'll have only one subscribe there that triggers on page load (component init);

Comment: Thanks, this works! But it is okay to put a subscribe inside a subscribe?

Comment: Right now, your data is fetched only once. so the subscription triggers only once. Therefore for this situation, this seems fine.
Otherwise, you can do something that I've suggested in my answer just now.